Black screen after login on Wayland but not on Xorg
Recently my laptop was working OK. Two days ago, I rebooted the machine once, then this problem occurred. The laptop can boot normally and shows the login screen.

If I try to log in with the Ubuntu option on Wayland I get a black screen, and I need to hold down the power button to reboot the system.
If I log in with the Ubuntu option on Xorg, then the system works fine without any problem.


Maybe the black screen and inability to boot to when Wayland display server is selected was caused by a recent update to a package related to your laptop's graphics. If so, the easiest thing to do would be to select Xorg instead of Wayland at the login screen when logging in.
